# Calculation percentage of my data for different number ranges

Tags: python, excel, google-sheets

I am trying to find out how to calculate percentage of my data for different number ranges. So I have a data that looks like this:

```
0.81761
0.255319
0.359551
0.210191
0.374046
0.188406
0.179487
0.265152
0.207792
0.202614
0.150943
```

..and I have these ranges:

```
0-0.3
0.3-0.7
0.7-1
```

I want to know out of my data, what is the percentage that fall into a specific number range. So, for example:

```
0-0.3 -> 72.7%
0.3-0.7 -> 18.18%
0.7-1 -> 9.09%
```

Does anybody knows how to do this calculation?

Comment: I don't use Sheets, but I am curious how you are obtaining the results you show in your example.  I see eight values in the range 0-0.3 and 8/11 is not 75%

Comment: I have used it just as an example for the output. If I can calculate this I wouldnt post this question here.. I have just changed it and added python as an option as well

Comment: In Excel you could use countif or frequency. There must be something similar in sheets

Comment: I have tried `COUNTIF` function but I am having problem to assign ranges of numbers: `=COUNTIF(my_data, my_ranges)` it gives me result `0`, I think because it cant assign the ranges (0-0.3 ...)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `COUNTIF` and `COUNTIFS`, you can better refer to each "bin" individually:  eg:

[image]

If you want to refer to your entire range of "bins" in the same formula, then you can use the `FREQUENCY` function (at least in Excel), but the formula needs to be entered as an array formula over the results range:

[image]